# Erase part of a string from i to the end of the line

Tags: c++, string

I need to make a program that will take in a program, strip all its `//` and `/* */` comments, and finally send that to a new file.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to end the deletion of characters in a string by `s.erase` at the end of a line of the comment. I entered the whole program into a string, and now I have to find and erase the comments.

```
while (!(filein.eof()))
{
    ch=filein.get();
    s.insert(i,1,ch);
    i++;
}
for (i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    if((s.at(i) == '/') && (s.at(i+1) == '/'))
    {
        s.erase(i, '\n');
    }
}
```

I thought `s.erase(i, '\n')` will work but it only erases the first 10 characters.

Comment: The second parameter to erase is count not a character.

Comment: Your program takes in a cpp file, not a binary / executable file, right? Do you have to use the string class and its methods specifically?

Comment: Yes, the program does take in a cpp file. I have to use a string as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII code of character escape literal '\n' is equal to 10. So this call

```
s.erase(i, '\n')
```

means to remove 10 characters starting from position i.

You need something as the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "// This is a comment\n a + b/* it is a sum */= c" );

    std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"" << std::endl;

    typedef std::string::size_type size_type;

    if ( s.length() > 1 )
    {
        for ( size_type i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++ )
        {
            if ( s[i] == '/' )
            {
                if ( s[i+1] == '/' )
                { 
                    size_type n = s.find( '\n', i + 2 );
                    n = n == std::string::npos ? s.length() - i : n - i + 1; 
                    s.erase( i, n );
                }
                else if ( s[i+1] == '*' )
                { 
                    size_type n = s.find( "*/", i + 2 );
                    n = n == std::string::npos ? s.length() - i : n - i + 2; 
                    s.replace( i, n, 1, ' ' );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
"// This is a comment
 a + b/* it is a sum */= c"
" a + b = c"
```

Take into account that this code ignores a backslash character `(\)` immediately followed by a new-line character that is deleted by the preprocessor splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

Comment: @DOUGLAS O. MOEN I have not understood what you are speaking about.

Comment: @DOUGLAS O. MOEN The problem is my bad English.:)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the documentation for erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), you'll see:

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

What's happening with your `s.erase(i, '\n')` is that the `'\n'` character - which is a linefeed with ASCII code 10 - is matching the `count` paramter, causing 10 characters to be erased.  That's because the `char` type is an integral type and subject to Standard Conversions to other larger integral types such as `size_type` (see section 4.5 Integral Promotions in the Standard - [draft here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)).

Instead, you should use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the offset/index where the comment starts and terminates and calculate the number of character to erase....

If you look at `find`...

```
size_type find( const basic_string& str, size_type pos = 0 ) const;
```

...you'll see there's a `pos` parameter that defaults to 0 - that's the offset in the string at which to start searching for `str`.  So, you can get a range of characters that constitute a C style `/* ... */` comment link this:

```
while (true)
{
    std::string::size_type from = line.find("/*");
    if (from == std::string::npos)
        break;
    // a comment begins inside the line

    std::strings::size_type to = line.find("*/", from);
    if (to != std::string::npos)
        line.erase(from, to - from);
    else
        line.erase(from); // rest of the line...
}
```

The above is NOT a drop in solution... you should think about how to handle lines after a line with `/*` but no matching `*/`.  It's not particularly hard, but you won't learn if I don't leave you something to do.

---

Separately, rather than reading the file a character at a time...

```
while (!(filein.eof()))
{
    ch=filein.get();
    s.insert(i,1,ch);
    i++;
}
```

...you can (assuming you're not dealing with a binary file that may legitimately contain a NUL `'\0'` character) simply say...

```
if (std::getline(filein, s, '\0'))
{
    ...it_worked, use s here...
}
else
    std::cerr << "error reading from filein\n";
```

Comment: About reading the file, I should just stick to reading on character at a time since that's how I learned in class. Can you explain more on std::string::find? Sorry as I am in an introductory C++ class.